# checking both scrollTop and id offset for sticky menu in single condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check the scroll position is greater than 350 and menuSticky offset position is 92 in same condition.that condition is not working.I gave my piece of code

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    
   if($(document).scrollTop() > 350) {
    $('.secMenu').addClass('menuSticky');
     
   } else {
    $('.secMenu').removeClass('menuSticky');
   }
        
    var menu = $('.menuSticky');  //shows error
             // var menu = $('.secMenu'); working
   var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top; 
    console.log(menu.offset().top);                  
      if((($('.menuSticky').offset.top)==92)) {
      console.log('true');
      $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
     $('.secMenu').hide();
                 $(this).toggleClass("open");
   }).mouseleave(function(){
     $('.secMenu').show();
   });    
     }    

 
});
```

```css
 .menuSticky{
   /*top:14%; */
   top:92px;
   z-index:999;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
   left:1.1%; 
   
    }
#consultant,#segment,#partner,#insights{
min-height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row secMenu">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 menu">
   <ul class="nav navMenu">
     <li class="test1"  ><a href="#consulting">Consulting & Solutions</a></li>
     <li class="test2" ><a href="#segments">Segments</a></li>
     <li class="test3" ><a href="#partner">Our Partners</a></li>
     <li class="test4" ><a href="#insights">Perspectives</a></li>
   </ul>  
  </div>
    </div>   <!--End of second menu -->

<div class="" id="consultant">consultant
</div>
<div class="" id="segment">segment
</div>
<div class="" id="partner">partner
</div>
<div class="" id="insights">insights
</div>
```

updated

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > 350) {
    $('.secMenu').addClass('menuSticky');
     
   } else {
    $('.secMenu').removeClass('menuSticky');
   }
var menu = $('.menuSticky');
    console.log(menu.length);
   if (menu.length==1) {   
    
   var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top; 
    console.log(menu.offset().top);     
 $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
     $('.menuSticky').hide();
                 $(this).toggleClass("open");
   }).mouseleave(function(){
     $('.menuSticky').show();
   });              
        
   }  
  });
```

```css
.menuSticky{
   /*top:14%; */
   top:92px;
   z-index:999;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
   left:1.1%; 
   
    }
#consultant,#segment,#partner,#insights{
min-height:100vh;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row secMenu">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 menu">
   <ul class="nav navMenu">
     <li class="test1"  ><a href="#consulting">Consulting & Solutions</a></li>
     <li class="test2" ><a href="#segments">Segments</a></li>
     <li class="test3" ><a href="#partner">Our Partners</a></li>
     <li class="test4" ><a href="#insights">Perspectives</a></li>
   </ul>  
  </div>
    </div>   <!--End of second menu -->

<div class="" id="consultant">consultant
</div>
<div class="" id="segment">segment
</div>
<div class="" id="partner">partner
</div>
<div class="" id="insights">insights
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your block of code have a condition to remove class menuSticky when scroll position less than 350px. So it will be a case you try to get offset top from an undefined variable *menu*.

To fix your issue, check menuSticky is existing before doing further.

```
var menu = $('.menuSticky');
if (menu.length) {
    var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;
    console.log(menu.offset().top);
    if ((($('.menuSticky').offset.top) == 92)) {
        console.log('true');
        $('.dropdown').hover(function () {
            $('.secMenu').hide();
            $(this).toggleClass("open");
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            $('.secMenu').show();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to console menu.length It show 1 when it is secMenu menuSticky and 0 for secMenu..by using this I tried to do my logic as updated post